# Value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ from the Taylor series $(1+x)^p=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n}x^n$. However, the Taylor series only converges for $|x|\lt1$ and $x=1$ in this case. I have already proved that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}$ converges I only need to prove that it converges to $2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: I have discussed the behavior of binomial series at $x=\pm 1$ in [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html?m=0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it converges, [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) tells you that\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}n&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}nx^n\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}(1+x)^{-1/2}\\&=2^{-1/2}.\end{align}